# How to create a pdf from html5 and css3 in Django?

Tags: django, html, css, pdf

I have a very simple use case. I want to create a pdf from a html file that I have.

Problem:

I have checked this tool. But it does not work for css3. And gives errors while parsing bootstrap files. 
[xhtml2pdf](http://www.xhtml2pdf.com/)

I am currently checking [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/python/) (giving some issues when I am running it.)

Has anyone faced such an issue and have you been able to solve it ?

Comment: Depending on your budget: look into Phantomjs+rasterize.js or PrinceXML or PDFRreactor. Also reportlab may help you...FAQ

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is also useful, but in my experience Prince is superior, though pricey.

Answer (score 2):

There is surprisingly very little options available when you are not prepared to pay for a commercial library. I had the same requirement from one of my clients that did not want to pay for any third party tools, so I had to make a plan. This is what I did, not the best solution, but it got the job done

1. I downloaded the newest version of [wkhtmltopdf](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/). Unfortunately the wkhtmltopdf tool did not display some of my google graphs embedded in my HTML when converting to PDF. So I used the wkhtmltoimage tool also included to convert to a PNG, which woked as expected and displayed all the graphs.
2. I then downloaded the newest version of [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) and converted the PNG to PDF.

I automated this process using C#. You should be able to do this using python as well (Please note that I have no knowledge of python, and could be wrong).

Unfortunately this is not the most elegant solution because you have to perform two conversions and do a bit of work to automate everyting, but this is the best solution I could come up with that gave me the desired results and quality.

Of course there are losts of commercial software out there that will do a faster and better job.

**Just a side note:**

The web page that I had to convert was devloped in HTML5 and CSS3 using version 3 of bootstrap and it contained some google graphs and charts. Everything was converted without any problems.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ImageMagick, not GhostScript. Updated the post. @AkashDeshpande